# Error al comparar contraseñas con Bcryptjs

Tags: nodejs, bcryptjs

Tengo problemas al momento de realizar una comparación de contraseñas encriptadas, no me permite continuar y detiene el servidor.

Este es el código para realizar la consulta a través de id que funciona sin problemas realizando consultas desde Postman y consultas por medio de email, que es donde presenta el error:

```
const db = require('../config/config');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const User = {};

User.findById = (id, result) => {
    const sql = `
        SELECT
            id,
            email,
            name,
            lastname,
            image,
            password
        FROM
            users
        WHERE
            id = ?
    `;

    db.query(
        sql,
        [id],
        (err, user) => {
            if(err){
                console.log('Error: ', err);
                result(err, null);
            }
            else{
                console.log('Usuario obtenido: ', user);
                result(null, user);
            }
        }
    )
}

User.findByEmail = (email, result) => {
    const sql = `
        SELECT
            id,
            email,
            name,
            lastname,
            image,
            password
        FROM
            users
        WHERE
            email = ?
    `;

    db.query(
        sql,
        [email],
        (err, user) => {
            if(err){
                console.log('Error: ', err);
                result(err, null);
            }
            else{
                console.log('Usuario obtenido: ', user);
                result(null, user);
            }
        }
    )
}


User.create = async (user, result) => {
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10);
    const sql = `
        INSERT INTO
            users(
                email,
                name,
                lastname,
                phone,
                image,
                password,
                created_at,
                updated_at
            )
            VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
    `;

    db.query(
        sql,
        [
            user.email,
            user.name,
            user.lastname,
            user.phone,
            user.image,
            hash,
            new Date(),
            new Date()
        ],
        (err, res) => {
            if(err){
                console.log('Error: ', err);
                result(err, null);
            }
            else{
                console.log('Id del nuevo usuario: ', res.insertId);
                result(null, res.insertId);
            }
        }
    )
}

module.exports = User;
```

Este es el error que arroja al realizar la consulta desde Postman:

```
D:\Desarrollo\pidelo_app_backend\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:286
                nextTick(callback.bind(this, Error("Illegal arguments: "+(typeof s)+', '+(typeof hash))));
                                             ^

Error: Illegal arguments: string, undefined
    at _async (D:\Desarrollo\pidelo_app_backend\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:286:46)
    at D:\Desarrollo\pidelo_app_backend\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:307:17
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at bcrypt.compare (D:\Desarrollo\pidelo_app_backend\node_modules\bcryptjs\dist\bcrypt.js:306:20)
    at D:\Desarrollo\pidelo_app_backend\controllers\usersController.js:28:50
    at Query.<anonymous> (D:\Desarrollo\pidelo_app_backend\models\user.js:62:17)
    at Query.<anonymous> (D:\Desarrollo\pidelo_app_backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Query._callback (D:\Desarrollo\pidelo_app_backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:488:16)
    at Sequence.end (D:\Desarrollo\pidelo_app_backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (D:\Desarrollo\pidelo_app_backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:149:8)

Node.js v18.16.1
```

Como se puede ver, encuentra al usuario realizando la consulta por email, pero al momento de comparar las contraseñas se detiene el servidor.

Controlador:

```
const User = require('../models/user');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const keys = require('../config/keys');

module.exports = {

    login(req, res){
        const email = req.body.email;
        const password = req.body.password;

        User.findByEmail(email, async (err, myUser) => {
            if(err) {
                return res.status(501).json({
                    success: false,
                    message: 'Hubo un error con el registro del usuario',
                    error: err
                });
            }

            if(myUser.length < 1) {
                return res.status(401).json({ //EL USUARIO NO TIENE AUTORIZACIÓN DE LOGIN
                    success: false,
                    message: 'No se encontró el e-mail'
                });
            }

            const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(password, myUser.password);

            if(isPasswordValid){
                const token = jwt.sign({id: myUser.id, email: myUser.email}, keys.secretOrKey,{});
                const data = {
                    id: myUser.id,
                    name: myUser.name,
                    lastname: myUser.lastname,
                    email: myUser.email,
                    phone: myUser.phone,
                    image: myUser.image,
                    session_token: `JWT ${token}`
                }

                return res.status(201).json({
                    success: true,
                    message: 'Autenticación exitosa.',
                    data: data //ID DEL NUEVO USUARIO
                });
            }
            else{
                return res.status(401).json({ //EL USUARIO NO TIENE AUTORIZACIÓN DE LOGIN
                    success: false,
                    message: 'El password es incorrecto'
                });
            }
        });
    },

    register(req, res){
        const user = req.body;
        User.create(user, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(501).json({
                    success: false,
                    message: 'Hubo un error con el registro del usuario',
                    error: err
                });
            }
            return res.status(201).json({
                success: true,
                message: 'El registro se realizo correctamente',
                data: data
            });
        });
    }
}

Al momento de realizar la consulta de login con Postman, el server arroja un error 500 y se desconecta no permitiendo así continuar, además se puede ver que si encuentra el usuario al realizar la búsqueda a traves del email.
```

Comment: Te fijaste si antes de await bcrypt.compare(password, myUser.password); el valor myUser.password es distinto a undefined?

Comment: Además si es que recibes el valor 'myUser' este deberia ser un arreglo, por lo que deberías poner bcrypt.compare(password, myUser[0].password);

Comment: Efectivamente valide y me aparece como "Undefined" pero no logro hacer la captura de la información (la consulta si se realiza pero no almacena este dato). Efectivamente! El problema era que no estaba declarando myUser como arreglo al realizar la comparación!